# Java Netbeans error with MS Acess

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans

um facing an error that's blowing my mind , I can't connect my JAVA code with MS access ... and i've been searching for hours now , and i've installed the ODBC of MS Driver and did all the steps ... and still getting this eror msg

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

what should i do .. I need help :/

here's the connection code :

```
public gdUI(MainUI myParentFrame) {
    this.myParentFrame = myParentFrame;
    this.setSize(600, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
    FillSeverity();
    //DataBAse Connection
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=substituting_DB.accdb;";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: Have you installed your ODBC as user datasource or system datasource?

Comment: If you have a 64 bit environment, please check this link http://www.selikoff.net/2011/07/26/connecting-to-ms-access-file-via-jdbc-in-64-bit-java/

Comment: i have 64bit but um using a 32 bit version of MS access

Comment: Check you are not mixing a 64 bit JVM with a 32 bit driver or vice versa! :)

Comment: i've checked the link but i'm missing something ...

Comment: if i'm using a JDK 64-bit and MS Access 32-bit , that will make this error ?

Comment: I think that this mismatching is the cause of your problem

Answer (score 1):

As I find the need to install/configure a data source under Windows a no-go, as MS-Access does not need it too, I suggest to use another driver [ucanaccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html):

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
String database = "jdbc:ucanaccess:////.../substituting_DB.accdb";
```

The driver needs additional libraries; I had the following library dependencies in my maven build:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.ucanaccess</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```